# Calculating the sum of integers from x to y with a while loop

Tags: scala, sum

I'm trying to write a code in Scala to calculate the sum of elements from x to y using a while loop.
I initialize x and y to for instance :

```
val x = 1
val y = 10
```

then I write a while loop to increment x :

```
while (x<y) x = x + 1
```

But println(x) gives the result 10 so I'm assuming the code basically does 1 + 1 + ... + 1 10 times, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to find the sum via a range, converted to a list:

```
val x = 1
val y = 10
val sum = (x to y).toList.sum
println("sum = " + sum)
```

**Output:**

```
sum = 55
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: It works but I wanted to make it work with a while loop. User @PARAMESWARA REDDY gave the correct code. Thanks!

Comment: @SidiAli while loops and mutable variables aren't idiomatic scala. Don't use them. Just pretend they do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do it using a (yak!) `while` loop with `var`s:

```
var x = 1 // Note that is a "var" not a "val"
val y = 10
var sum = 0 // Must be a "var"
while(x <= y) { // Note less than or equal to
  sum += x
  x += 1
}
println(s"Sum is $sum") // Sum = 55 (= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10)
```

Here's another, more functional, approach using a recursive function. Note the complete lack of `var` types.

```
val y = 10
@scala.annotation.tailrec // Signifies add must be tail recursive
def add(x: Int, sum: Int): Int = {

  // If x exceeds y, then return the current sum value.
  if(x > y) sum

  // Otherwise, perform another iteration adding 1 to x and x to sum.
  else add(x + 1, sum + x)
}

// Start things off and get the result (55).
val result = add(1, 0)
println(s"Sum is $result") // Sum is 55
```

Here's a common functional approach that can be used with collections. Firstly, `(x to y)` becomes a `Range` of values between 1 and 10 inclusive. We then use the `foldLeft` *higher-order function* to sum the members:

```
val x = 1
val y = 10
val result = (x to y).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
println(s"Sum is $result") // Sum is 55
```

The `(0)` is the initial sum value, and the (`_ + _`) adds the current sum to the current value. (This is *Scala* shorthand for `((sum: Int, i: Int) => sum + i)`).

Finally, here's a simplified version of the elegant functional version that @TimBiegeleisen posted above. However, since a `Range` already implements a `.sum` member, there is no need to convert to a `List` first:

```
val x = 1
val y = 10
val result = (x to y).sum
println(s"Sum is $result") // Sum is 55
```

(`sum` can be thought of as being equivalent to the `foldLeft` example above, and is typically implemented in similar fashion.)

BTW, if you just want to sum values from 1 to 10, the following code does this very succinctly:

```
(1 to 10).sum
```

Although you can use *Scala* to write *imperative* code (which uses `var`s, `while` loops, etc. and which inherently leads to *shared mutable state*), I strongly recommend that you consider *functional* alternatives. *Functional* programming avoids the *side-effects* and complexities of *shared mutable state* and often results in simpler, more elegant code. Note that all but the first examples are all functional.

Answer (score -3):

```
var x = 1
var y = 10    
var temp = 0

while (x < y) {
    temp = temp+x
    x = x + 1
}

println(temp)
```

This gives required result

Comment: This yields an answer of 45, not 55. The `while` loop condition ought to be `x <= y`, not `x < y`; this version doesn't include 10 in the result.